# Finding the intermediate points of a line segment on a surface of constant non-zero curvature

Tags: geometry, polar-coordinates, surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

Suppose a surface with constant curvature $C$ in which are two points $P_1$ and $P_2$, described using polar coordinates from origin $O$.

[Diagram here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3Mun.png)

As I draw a line from the origin at some angle $\theta$ (such that $\theta_1 \geq \theta \geq \theta_2$) this line will intersect the line segment $\bar{P_1 P_2}$. I am interested in finding the coordinates of this intersection.

Comment: Negative curvature?

Comment: @new-qopenglwidget I would appreciate answers for C=-1, or for C=1, or a general formula for arbitrary constant curvature if one exists.

For my purposes, approximations would also be useful.